# Перегрузка методов с#

Tags: c#

Чем вредна и полезна перегрузка методов в с#?

Comment: Закрывальщики, руки прочь! Вопрос хороший.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возьмем для начала язык не поддерживающий перегрузку, например C. Допустим нужно две функции, выполняющих вычисление одной и той же величины, но с использованием разного набора параметров. Как такое реализовать? Создать две функции с разными именами. При этом желательно сохранить осмысленность названий и показать факт того, что две, а может и больше, функции по сути выполняют одно и тоже и отличаются только именем.

Теперь вернемся к языкам поддерживающим перегрузку. По сути, все осталось как и раньше, но для одинаковых по сути функций/методов есть возможность сохранить одно имя на всех.

Такой эффект удалось получить расширив понятие имени функции, включающего только собственно имя, до сигнатуры функции/метода, которая, кроме имени, включает также список типов параметров и тип возвращаемого значения. Имена параметров в сигнатуру не входят. Это позволяет различать функции имеющие одинаковые имена, но различные по величине и составу наборы параметров. Тип возвращаемого значения, не смотря на то, что является частью сигнатуры, при перегрузке не рассматривается ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173114.aspx#Anchor_0)).

Разумеется такое решение не без недостатков. Например, мы не сможем таким образом создать в одной области видимости две функции для вычисления какой либо физической величины по двум разным формулам, но с одинаковым числом и типом параметров. С точки зрения физики, это два разных метода вычисляющих одно и тоже значение, но, для существующей модели перегрузки методов, они не различимы.

Также есть некоторые особенности поведения перегруженных методов при наследовании в сравнении с другими языками, но это уже отдельная тема. Для ознакомления с проблемой можно почитать [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149287/)

C# поддерживает также значения параметров по умолчанию, которые позволяют не создавать множество перегруженных методов для различного набора одних и тех же параметров.