# Перегрузка метода

Tags: c#, методы, перегрузка-операторов

Мой код может пойти по 8 веткам. Т.е. к примеру 1 и тот же метод должен принимать 2 параметра типа Encoding, только первая перегрузка работает с System.Text.Encoding.ASCII и System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, а вторая с System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 и System.Text.Encoding.Unicode. Как реализовать такую конструкцию без тучи if-ов либо switch-case?

Comment: перегрузку сделать не получится, т.к. у ваших методов будет одинаковая сигнатура, а для перегруженных методов сигнатура обязана отличаться. Тут еще почитайте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490768/198316

Comment: стоит добавить пример кода.

Comment: @rdorn а как тогда реализовать без использование if и switch?

Comment: А чем они вас не устраивают? Конкретно в таком случае никак. Допишите чего хотите добиться этими манипуляциями и как пробовали сделать, тогда можно будет подумать как это сделать, с телепатией у меня сегодня не очень =).

Comment: Может, стоит сделать два метода? Что-то типа `MethodAsciiUnicode` и `MethodUtf8Unicode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тот же Фаулер советует избавиться от switch и if с помощью полиморфизма (вот пример https://refactoring.guru/ru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism). Может это ваш вариант